# Symfony, grunt, requires.js and Assetic

Tags: javascript, symfony, less, assetic, gruntjs

Our application uses a combination of amd loaded js and css defined using less. For our dev environments we run using the individual files and use front end scripts.  However for production I am keen to remove the front end requirements and also compile / compress the libs.

Currently we can do this outside symfony using grunt - however it would be very desirable to automate this and integrate this with the symfony system.

For example:

Dev: Assetic maps the files from the bundles using symbolic links - this allows editing and testing within the project.

Prod: Assetic runs Grunt and compresses the files before deploying them into the web directory.

I am keen to retain the integration with twig templates and also versioning of files that Assetic provides.

Clearly grunt does overlap with Assetic - but do they / can they play nicely together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use Assetic unless there is something specific that you need to use Grunt for.  They can co-exist and play nicely but the overlap seems very redundant.  We use multiple filters with Assetic for our automated deployments and instead of using require.js we have additional script blocks that we override on a per-template basis so that we aren't loading scripts on pages that don't need it.

Here is what our Assetic looks like with some of the filter configurations:

```
assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
bundles:        ['AcmeBundle', 'FOSUserBundle', 'FooBundle']
java:           /usr/local/bin/java
filters:
    less:
        node:       /usr/local/bin/node
        node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules]
        apply_to:   "\.less$"
    cssrewrite: ~
    cssembed:
        jar:      %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/cssembed-0.4.5.jar
        apply_to: "\.css$|\.less$"
    yui_css:
        jar:      %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        apply_to: "\.css$"
    yui_js:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        apply_to: "\.js$"
    closure:
        jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
```